# Locating the source of managed exceptions that aren't coming directly from my code?

Tags: c#, exception

I apologize in advance if this is really a Super User question... I just wasn't sure, but this seems more on the dev. side than on the tech support side.  :)

This isn't necessarily a problem, but it does actually drive me totally bonkers on my system.  It also only happens on my computer.

When I launch any application, even a blank WPF application, I see **four** exceptions:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

To figure out where these are coming from, I then set VS2008 to break on any thrown CLR exceptions, and here is the information:

Exception #1:
Cannot find a part of the path 'D:\Dell\Reader2.0\SPLASH.SYS\fonts\AscenderUni.ttf'.

Exception #2:
Culture name 'ug' is not supported.
Parameter name: name

Exception #3:
Culture name 'ug' is not supported.
Parameter name: name

Exception #4:
There is no registered CultureInfo with the IetfLanguageTag 'ug'.

I've poked through Process Monitor and Process Explorer.  Process Monitor shows that my application is doing a RegQueryValue, which I'm certainly not responsible for... but some DLL (presumably from Dell crapware) is getting loaded by my process and is reading this regkey.  I then looked at Process Explorer, hoping to see which DLLs my application is loading, but can't find that info.  I then tried PrcView and saw the modules my application was loading.

I was surprised to see how many other modules were getting loaded, but I didn't see anything Dell related.  I'm also wondering how it is possible that a Norton Internet Security DLL got loaded into my process, but I assume that's intended and something special that Norton does to ensure that a process is safe to execute.

What else can I do to identify and remove where these exceptions are coming from?

**UPDATE**

Not sure if it's confusing what I'm getting at here.  This exception is raised in a DLL that my application loads for some reason (I don't reference anything Dell-related from my project).  I've now uninstalled that app, and I *still* get the stupid exceptions.  It's all technically fine because the exception is handled *somewhere*, presumably within that DLL, but I'm just annoyed because four extra messages (actually 8, since I have to close two dialogs per exception) pop up when I run my application.  Call me lazy, but I never asked this damn DLL to load in the first place.  :)

Perhaps now it's time to use msconfig to start disabling some Dell services.  I'll play with that later when I actually have free time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No file corruption.  As I've been trying to hunt this one down for a while, I figured out what happened.  Somewhere along the way, a font was installed with Uighur culture, which is, apparently a Turkish/Chinese culture (as best as I can tell), and their CultureInfo tag?  "ug". When the fonts were cached, the system was attempting to load the Uighur culture.  Sadly, my installation of Windows seems to be conspicuously missing this culture in Windows.  Knowing that I won't be using the culture on my machine anytime soon, I followed the directions on MSDN to create and install a new culture.

Though the error won't hurt anything major.  It *is* just a first chance exception, after all, it was annoying the crap out of me.  So here's what I did.

1. Create a new console app.
2. Add a reference to sysglobal.
3. Add the following code:

   ```
       var culture = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("ug", CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
       var ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
       var ri = new RegionInfo("US");
       culture.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(ci);
       culture.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(ri);
       culture.Register();
   ```
4. Build.
5. From Windows Explorer (you need admin privileges to do this), run the compiled executable as administrator.

If all goes well, there should now be a file in C:\windows\Globalization called "ug.nlp".

You shouldn't receive that message again.

Comment: Dude, that's awesome.  I'm going to give this a try ASAP.  Can't believe someone tracked this one down!  :)

Comment: I tracked it down because I'm tired of hitting "F5" twelve times to get into my application.  Sigh.  Oh yeah, and this was the *only* place I've seen this error posted online.

Comment: I got this error today after installing Open Office on a Windows 8 system.  Guess MS does not like Open Office too much.  Your solution made the error go away.

Comment: I am getting an error "Cannot replace built-in culture ug without specifying the CultureAndRegionModifiers.Replacement flag" when I execute above code, why is that?

Comment: When you get the exection "Cannot replace built-in culture ug without specifying the CultureAndRegionModifiers.Replacement flag" it could mean your applications use different runtimes. The application which gave me the problems was a 3.0 (or 3.5) application while my first try for the code above was a 4.0 application. When i switched to 3.0 i got what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
It disappear after I did:

Clear the WPF font cache and restarted Visual Studio.
Clear the cache: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937135

Éric

Answer (score 1):

It is *very* unlikely to be the shovel-ware on your machine.  These DLLs need to inject themselves also into non-managed programs, they have to be written in a language that doesn't depend on the CLR, like C or C++.  And accordingly cannot generate managed exceptions.

These exceptions look like machine configuration problems to me.  Junk in your registry.  The bad culture name (sounds like "us" got corrupted to "ug") generates three of them, the font is probably listed in the registry but missing from the disk.

Short from a OS reinstall, you could possibly diagnose this by using both ProcMon and the debugger.  Use Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox to force the debugger to stop on the first-chance exception.  When it hits, switch to ProcMon, the registry key or file should be visible very near the end of the trace.

Comment: that's definitely what I had done -- my usual debugging steps in .NET development always go back to checking the box to break when the exception is thrown.  I also used Process Monitor to filter on the regkey, and it looks like it's coming from my application.  But I know that it's not coming directly from *my own* code, so I am stumped.  I can't find anything on the web about this particular file it's trying to open.

Comment: Well, it looks like the DLL trying to load the font must be the Dell ON Reader 2.0 (whatever that is... probably the media card reader, which my computer doesn't even have).  I uninstalled the app, and the problem is still there.  Ugh.

Comment: @Dave, not quite, it means that something in `PresentationCore.dll` is trying to load a *font* file from `D:\Dell\Reader2.0\SPLASH.SYS\fonts\AscenderUni.ttf`. Presumably, as Hans has said **WPF** is trying to load the font because of something you're calling from your code that's in `PresentationCore.dll`

Comment: @Rob perhaps the solution is to find that stupid font and put it on my computer.  :)  Of course, that wouldn't solve the "ug" issue.  I'll try this again, because I just realized that when I was using process monitor, I was not filtering for "ug".

Answer (score 1):

With leads from the above answers I was able to solve this issue by deleting the font "Microsoft Uighur Regular"

Comment: There is no font with that name. There is font that use the culture info : Uighur. I did'nt found how to find the faulty font if any. It sounds like a wpf font cache corruption to me.

Answer (score 0):

First chance exceptions are normal - these are displayed whenever an exception is thrown, whether it was handled or not. They exist so you *can* go into your code and find out why they are thrown.

However, if the exception has been handled, there is no problem and execution will resume.

If the exception was not handled, a second chance exception will be caught by the debugger and execution will halt.

This is normal and shouldn't be of concern. You can always hide them - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380/avoiding-first-chance-exception-messages-when-the-exception-is-safely-handled) question and answers for more details.

In regards to the actual exceptions - there is some code (third party or your own) that is trying to access a `ttf` in the mentioned directory, this cannot be found, hence the exception (which was handled, so no problem).

The other exceptions are due to create a [non existing](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/) CultureInfo (`ug`) - perhaps this is supposed to be `uk`? Check configuration and code for this.

These values may be configured in the registry.

Comment: I understand, and the funny part is that I don't handle these exceptions anywhere in my code, so it must be handled by whatever DLL is getting loaded.  I'm hoping to find out what DLL this is, so I can uninstall / delete it from my system.  I know I can safely ignore this, but the reason why it's getting on my nerves is that when I have problems debugging, I turn on the option to break whenever the first exception is thrown, and I always have to F5 through these.  Small beans, but still annoying.  :)  Good point about the CultureInfo -- I hadn't ever looked into this.  US or UK I guess.

Comment: @Dave: What you’re saying amounts to saying that WPF should never use exceptions anywhere in its code. That doesn’t make sense. Exceptions are a normal, standard feature of the environment.

Comment: @Timwi What I am trying to do is to determine the source of an exception that comes from a DLL that I didn't explicitly load myself.  I am perfectly fine with exceptions... not sure why you think I'm saying otherwise.  :)