# Visual Studio error while debugging : FileNotFoundException: arimon__.ttf and arimonbd.ttf, ArgumentException Culture name 'UG' not supported

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, exception, fonts, culture

I red the question/answer:

[Locating the source of managed exceptions that aren't coming directly from my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646488/locating-the-source-of-managed-exceptions-that-arent-coming-directly-from-my-co) at stack overflow but couldn't really figure it out how to really fix my problem instead of creating a new culture to hide the problem.

Does anybody else had the same problem or have a suggestion ?

I have Windows Vista Enterprise French(initial installation) but running in English.

Edited: ...
I have fixed (or hide) my problem by changing the 3 projects configuration of my solution from target frameworks 3.5 to 4. The problem disapear but I would really like to know what was the cause of it. Any good advise that could lead me to understand what was the cause will get the "Right answer"...

Comment: I have fixed (or hide) my problem by changing the 3 projects configuration of my solution from target frameworks 3.5 to 4. The problem disapear but I would really like to know what was the cause of it. Any good advise that could lead me to understand what was the cause will get the "Right answer"... thanks Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed (or hide) my problem by changing the 3 projects configuration of my solution from target frameworks 3.5 to 4. The problem disapear but I would really like to know what was the cause of it.