# Delete Exception Message from Output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, output

I'm debugging my application, so I use code like `Debug.WriteLine();` a lot. The problem is that I also have thread running that is getting an `TimeoutException` almost every 500 milliseconds, it is not a problem that I receive this error, because I'm receiving data from a serialport, the problem is that it fills up my Output log too fast, to read other messages that I created myself.

**Question:** How do I delete the following exception from my Output log: `A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in System.dll`?

**Answer:**

Problem has been answered with 2 ways to get rid of the exceptions in the output log:

**First Method by Tim Coker:**

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Windows -> Exception Messages to off.

**Second Method by Charlie Kilian**

Right mouse on the Output Log, Uncheck Exception Messages.

Comment: I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60765/645511) has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak what goes to the output window via Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window.  You probably want to disable "Exception Messages."

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks will mark this as the answer as soon as I'am allowed to do so

Comment: Nice but silencing only the timeoutexception would be much better.