# I got this error when I program. Morw

Tags: vb.net

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. This one will halt the program even on try catch:

```
Try
  client = New TcpClient(whoisServerToTry, 43)
Catch ex As Exception
  Return ""
End Try
```

My logs are full with these errors:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
```

Moreoever, my computer often ocassionally freeze, I wonder if the damage is hardware.

Anyway I can debug this? This may be a super user stuff. However, super user doesn't know system.io.ioexception.

Comment: There is more information in these exceptions that you are not displaying.  You need to show the entire stack trace.

Comment: [first chance exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564681/what-is-a-first-chance-exception) and how to [avoid the messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380/avoiding-first-chance-exception-messages-when-the-exception-is-safely-handled)